# How to use transparent text on image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

Recently I have seen an apps, which has an image with text.

Whether the app used `ImageView` and `TextView`? How does the text overlay the image? How has it been done?

I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: use frame-layout and put textview on imgeview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the attribute android:background="#00000000" on your TextView in the layout. XML file.

```
<FrameLayout 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

/>

<TextView
android:height="match_parent"
android:width="match_parent"
android:background="#00000000" 
android:gravity="bottom"
/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can either use FrameLayout to put TextView on ImageView or
 You can take a text view with the background resouce as your image , something like this
Example:

```
 <TextView
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@drawable/custom_buttonclick"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Relative Layout, ImageView and TextView you can achieve this put background color of textView to transperent.